# Can $n$ half planes with the intersection pattern of a given tournament graph be realized?

Tags: geometry, graph-theory, computational-geometry, discrete-geometry

Consider an oriented complete graph, i.e. a tournament $G=(V,E)$

Ex:[image: example of a tournament graph. Colors serve to label nodes and have nothing to do with graph color (although that concept may have something to do with the solution)]

Let $A(i\in V)=\{j\in V|(j,i)\in V\}\cup\{i\}$.
Is there an efficient way of knowing if it is possible to find a set of half planes $h_i\subset \mathbb{R}^2, i\in V$ s.t. $k\notin A(i)\rightarrow \bigcap_{j\in A(i)}h_j\not\subset h_k$

Ex:
[image]

context: shows up in the study of causality in 2+1 spacetime.

Comment: Do you mean that as a one-way implication? If so, it's possible to find a set of half-planes that will work for any tournament: one satisfying $\bigcap_{i \in I} h_i \not\subset h_j$ whenever $j \notin I$.

Comment: Yes, a one way implication. What is the construction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take as your half-planes 
$$
    h_i = \left\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2: \frac{x}{i} + \frac{y}{n+1-i} \ge 1\right\}.
$$
For $n=5$, for example, we get:

[image]

The idea here is that each half-plane $h_i$ has a segment where its boundary is the boundary of the $n$-fold intersection $\bigcap_{j=1}^n h_j$. Let $P_i$ be a point slightly outside $h_i$ near the midpoint of that segment; then $P_i \notin h_i$ but $P_i \in h_j$ for all $j \ne i$. For a concrete example, take $P_i = (\frac{i^2-1}{n+1}, \frac{(n+1-i)^2-1}{n+1})$, though other points will also work.

Whatever the tournament is, and whatever the sets $A(i)$ are, if $k \notin A(i)$, then $$\bigcap_{j\in A(i)}h_j\not\subset h_k$$
because $P_k$ is in the intersection on the left-hand side but not in $h_k$.